# something wrong with the letters placemeent on buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a very beginner in JavaScript / jQuery and got some difficulties with my code. 
I am writing "Guess the word game" and the problem itself is that I have a 6-letters-length shuffled word from array and I need to place only one letter for one of 6 buttons. I have 6 buttons named from Letter1 to Letter6. Please, look through my code and say where is a mistake in placing it, thanks in advance. The code :

```
String.prototype.shuffle = function () {
    var a = this.split(""),
        n = a.length;
    for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
    return a.join("");
}
$("#start").on('click', function () {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    var shuffledWord = words[rand].shuffle();
    /*alert (shuffledWord);*/
    for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWord.length; i++) {
        $('Letter1').text(shuffledWord[i]);
        $('Letter2').text(shuffledWord[i]);
        $('Letter3').text(shuffledWord[i]);
        $('Letter4').text(shuffledWord[i]);
        $('Letter5').text(shuffledWord[i]);
        $('Letter6').text(shuffledWord[i]);
    }
});
```

The code itself works well, the problem is that I am doing something wrong with Letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to make it `$('#Letter1')` etc.--i.e., I think you left off the `#` in referring to the letter elements.